# Code coverage with .NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, code-coverage, dotcover

I am trying to setup code coverage on our **ASP.NET Core 2.0** web application. I use **dotcover** (from JetBrains) to provide code coverage on all my other builds (by running dotcover from the command-line during the build process).

When I run dotcover from our build server for our .NET Core 2.0 web app I see this.

[image]

It states that it has run successfully but then just hangs there and no code coverage files are created.

```
dotcover analyse /TargetExecutable:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" /TargetArguments:"test MyUnitTests.csproj" /Output:report.html /ReportType:HTML /LogFile=dotcover.log
```

If I try and add code coverage collection I see this.

[image]

```
dotcover analyse /TargetExecutable:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" /TargetArguments:"test MyUnitTests.csproj --collect:coverage" /Output:report.html /ReportType:HTML /LogFile=dotcover.log
```

And finally if I run **dotnet test** on its own (without dotcover) it seems to have worked, but again no coverage output is created.

[image]

```
dotnet test "MyUnitTests.csproj" -- collect:coverage
```

I'm unsure how to generate code coverage for a .NET Core 2.0 app, and not sure how / what data collectors are and how they should be used. Is dotcover the data collector in this example?

Basically, I just want to generate code coverage for a .NET Core 2.0 application.

**UPDATE:**

As per the suggestion I have installed *coverlet* as an alternative to *dotcover*. I have got it working but am getting inconsistent behaviour. When I run my batch file from the server it's all fine.

[image]

But when run from TFS I get an error.

[image]

**System.IO.FileNotFoundException: No test is available in . Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" and framework version settings are appropriate and try again.**

My project **does** have a reference to that assembly (it's installed by default by VS itself when you create a unit test project).

Why is TFS complaining about that assembly when it's definitely there and can be run manually from the command-line without an error?

Comment: I wonder as it's a paid product, why not contact them directly... they had been really helpful in the past. If you get an answer, then you can add it here, so we all know if come across to this same issue.

Comment: @balexandre  - Likewise I have found their support good but their command line tools are free so there may not be enough impetus there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if dotcover can works with net core, but you can take a look for [coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet), also you can find an example here: [Cross platform code coverage arrives for .NET Core](https://tattoocoder.com/cross-platform-code-coverage-arrives-for-net-core/)

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but getting inconsistent behaviour. See my update. Thanks.

Comment: it does state on [their page](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/features/): "dotCover calculates and reports statement-level code coverage in applications targeting .NET Framework, Silverlight, **and .NET Core**"

Comment: @balexandre Yes I was hoping to get it up and running fairly quickly, as I use it on all my other builds  and it works perfectly and produces awesome code coverage output. I'm getting an error using it hence my question here.

Comment: The way to get coverlet working with TFS is to explicitly specify the name of the project and suppress it from doing a build and restore e.g. dotnet test "MyProject.Tests.csproj" --no-build --no-restore /p:CollectCoverage=true

Comment: Although this didn't answer my original question I am satisfied enough with your proposed solution to mark this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Trying to implement and having issues::: See my notes at this question for implementation. (I just figured out the magic!)  Its a little bit tricky on Linux.. spoiler, you need to "dotnet publish" the UnitTest csproj.....https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet/issues/521

Answer (score 3):

I have just migrated a project from net461 to dotnet core and I wanted to maintain code coverage. Using the command line suggested by the OP was what I needed. I am migrating fake scripts where I was previously using dot cover to generate the snapshot file to be pushed to teamcity and an html report. I can confirm that the following works for me:

- DotNet SDK 2.1.2
- JetBrains.dotCover.CommandLineTools 2018.1.0

  - Also tested positive with 2017.1.20170403.131707
- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 15.7.0
- NUnit 3.10.1
- NUnit3TestAdapter 3.10.0

[**DotCover cover**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/dotCover__Console_Runner_Commands.html#cover)

```
<dotcoverpath>\dotCover.exe cover /TargetExecutable:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" /TargetArguments:"test --no-build --no-restore ./src/<test-project-root>" /Filters=+:<namespace-to-test> /Output:./bin/DotCover.snapshot
```

[**DotCover analyze**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/dotCover__Console_Runner_Commands.html#analyse)

I am not doing the following as I use the [DotCover report](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/dotCover__Console_Runner_Commands.html#report) command on the generated snapshot file but I can also confirm that the following is working for me as well.

```
<dotcoverpath>\dotCover.exe analyze /TargetExecutable:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" /TargetArguments:"test --no-build --no-restore ./src/<test-project-root>" /Filters=+:<namespace-to-test> /ReportType=HTML /Output:./bin/coverage.html
```

**Notes**

- In my test run I am not restoring packages (`--no-restore`) or compiling (`--no-build`) the project as I have already done this in a previous step. These can be removed to suit your needs.
- The OP did say that dot cover appeared to hang after the tests had completed. It is worth pointing out that the effort in turning the snapshot at the end of the test coverage into a report can take a while if there is a large amount of code and or assemblies. You do in fact see dot cover pausing at the point the tests have completed whilst it generates the html report. Use the filter (/Filters=) parameter to cut down on the size of things being covered, especially if you don't want to do any coverage on third party components.

> `/Filters=ARG` (Optional) Specifies coverage filters. Syntax:
>   `+:module=*;class=*;function=*;` Use `-:myassembly` to exclude an assembly from code coverage. Asterisk wildcard (`*`) is supported here

Comment: Very useful information, thanks very much. I'm currently using coverlet for my code coverage as per an earlier suggestion but will try again using your suggestion.